# GTK3 + OpenGL for windows: multiple GtkGLArea (ie. OpenGL contexts)

Tags: windows, opengl, gtk3, opengl-3, msys2

I am developing a GTK3 based application with OpenGL windows created using the [GtkGLArea widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGLArea.html), to build the application on windows I use the [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) 64 bits system. 
No problem to build the application, it works just with a single OpenGL window. 
However my program is designed to handle multiple projects, and hence GtkGLarea, one for each project. This works perfectly for Linux. 
However on window, it works with one GtkGLArea, but as soon as more than one are used only a single one (the first to be created) remains active, and no information is displayed in the other windows. If I click on any of the other windows then the content of the first window is updated with what should appear in the window I am interacting with ...

I noticed that I could open as many instances of my program each with one GtkGLAera working just fine, and therefore that the number of OpenGL context is not a problem, only the interaction / dialog / management within the same occurrence of my program is.

Is there any way to correct this behavior and how ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a known GDK Win32 bug that has been fixed.

[Bugzilla bug #789213](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=789213)

Answer (score 0):

You should use wglMakeCurrent() analog to set current context, and after usage you should call wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL) to release context so the other widget will be able to use OpenGL.